How to solve this integral used to define a distribution?
There's a result a paper on topological insulators uses
$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}|k|^{1/2}e^{-\mu|k|}\frac{dk}{2\pi} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}(x^2+\mu^2)^{-3/4}\cos\Big(\frac{3}{2}\tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{x}{\mu}\Big)\Big)$.
to help define a distribution. Can any integration wizard out there show how to derive this result? I thought of using Laplace transforms by taking
$I = 2\int_0^{\infty}\cos(kx)\sqrt{k}e^{-\mu k}\frac{dk}{2\pi}$
but didn't get very far with that approach.

Too long for a comment
$$I(\mu, x)=\int_0^\infty\cos(kx)\sqrt{k}e^{-\mu k}dk=\Re\int_0^{\infty}\sqrt k\,e^{-k(\mu-ix)}dk$$
A straightforward method of evaluation of such integrals is integration along a closed contour in the complex plane. Consider a segment of circle: $r\to R\to Re^{i\arctan\frac x\mu}\to re^{i\arctan\frac x\mu}\to r$, where we also added a small arch of the radius $r\to0$ around $z=0$; $\,R$ is the radius of a big arch ($R\to\infty$). The integrals along the both arches tend $\to0$; as there are no poles inside the segment
$$\oint \sqrt z\,e^{-z\sqrt{\mu^2+x^2}e^{-i\arctan\frac x\mu}}dz=0\,\Rightarrow\,\int_0^{\infty}\sqrt k\,e^{-k(\mu-ix)}dk=e^{\frac32i\arctan\frac xm}\int_0^\infty\sqrt t\,e^{-t\sqrt{\mu^2+x^2}}dt$$
Efficiently, we made the substitution $k=t\,e^{i\arctan\frac x\mu}$
Integrating,
$$I(\mu,x)=\Re \,e^{\frac32i\arctan\frac xm}(\mu^2+x^2)^{-\frac43}\Gamma\Big(\frac32\Big)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2(\mu^2+x^2)^\frac34}\cos\Big(\frac32\arctan\frac x\mu\Big)$$
